# how to manipulate the elements are loaded with js

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I have an ajax script to load json data from server.. and I create a radio button from this data using js.. after that I want to manipulate it with jQuery but I can't.. can you explain me?

This the ajax js..

```
function cs_mediaJson(link,selector)
{
$.getJSON(link,function(data){
        $.each(data,function(i,item){
            var openTag = "<div class='col-lg-2'>";
            var closeTag = "</div>";

            openTag += "<input class='media-radio' id='media-radio' type='radio' name='media-radio[]' value='"+item.id+"'>";
            openTag += "<label class='label'><img width='100%' height='100%' src='"+item.post_content+"100x100-"+item.post_title+"'></label>";
            openTag += closeTag;

            $(selector).append(openTag);
        });
});
}
```

The function of that code is to make radio button from json.. and I want to manipulate the radio button like, if I click it I will get the value and display the value to an input textbox ... please help me guys as I am new to JS

Comment: Where is the code with which you want to manipulate the radio button `media-radio`? Where and when exactly do you call it?

Comment: derbul69 yes, on media-radio, after dom was formed..

Answer (score 0):

After appending data, you should run these manipulating functions one more time

Answer (score 0):

You can use `on.(event, function(){...})`to manipulate an element that was added to the DOM afterwards.